# flies everywhere

Tags: windows, porch, insect

I have noticed tons of flies in the downstairs porch window and soon they where everywhere -- third, second and first floor windows/porches and even  some inside our home.  We have a tiny little entrance hallway in our house and I saw 6 or 7 flies in the window.  When I checked this morning there was only 1. There aren't any windows or anything so I have no clue where they came from.

I'm pretty terrified of flies so seeing so many really bothers me. There isn't any trash or dead animals that I know of.

Does anyone how I can figure out where they're coming from?

Comment: So they are mostly outside? Buy, or look up how to DIY a fly trap.

Comment: I'm not sure how to figure out where they're coming from, but I've had a similar issue where large flies (20-30 per day) seemed to literally appear out of nowhere. We didn't have any food out and we lived in an older building so the best theory I had was that there was a dead animal between our walls that was the food source and origin on the flies. This was terrifying and in the end we bought some "Fly Paper" and hung it around lights and windows to catch the flies and it was HIGHLY effective. It took about a week for the flies to go away but we never saw them again.

Answer (score 1):

Flies are attracted to strong smells like rotting food, feces, or sweets/sugar. They lay eggs near these food sources which only take a few days to hatch. You may be seeing flies that were attracted, or the flies that have hatched from eggs laid by flies that were attracted. If you can't smell food/feces/sweets in the area, you might ask someone for help. It's common to go "noseblind" to smells you're around all the time.

Flies are also attracted to windows/doors where it looks like they can get outside, usually either the nearest such area or the brightest/most appealing area. They'll repeatedly bash themselves against the glass. You can use this to your advantage to get rid of them; putting up a transparent sticky sheet in the corner of the window or door they seem to favor will trap many of them on the first contact. You then peel off the sheet once it's caught many flies and throw it away.

Put up some fly traps while you find the source of the flies; once the source is gone, the existing flies will eventually be caught by the traps.